# glVertexAttribPointer vec2 but forward just one

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I have this, wich will read in vec2, is it possible to forward just one, so the vertex shader will recieve in each 0,1 then 1,2 2,3 and so on?

```
float v[]{0,1,2,3,4...};
glVertexAttribPointer((GLuint)0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feels like a hack, but you could explicitely set the `stride` parameter of `glVertexAttribPointer` to the size of a single `float`.

Basically, whenever the GL fetches a vertex with index `i`, it will use the address `offset + i * stride`. The `0` you are using currently as stride parameter is a convenience shortcut meaning a tightly packed array, so it will be equivalent to `2 * sizeof(GLfloat)` in your case, but there is nothing in the GL which prevents you from setting a stride below that value of a tightly packed array:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(GLfloat), 0);
```

Comment: That answered the question, byt I'm still having problem, what I want is to access the previous vertex values in the shader, I only need the last one. You're right, that has a kind of hack, is there a better way?

Comment: @derhass, if you have to set the stride in tightly packed vec2 array, the stride should be: 2 *sizeof(GLfloat) not sizeof(GLfloat) as in your code.

Comment: @wangdq: that is true, but that is not what the question - and the answer - was about. I explicitely stated "but there is nothing in the GL which prevents you from setting a stride below that value of a tightly packed array:".